# Free GIS data that doesn't require attribution for printing on products

Tags: geospatial, uses-of-open-data, openstreetmap

I'm keen to make some products to sell with map graphics printed on them. As these are physical products (eg tshirt etc) I don't want to include the attribution in the design.

Is there a good source of GIS data available for commerical use without attributions?

Most require some sort of attribution. I'm talking pretty basic data such as country outlines, road lines, but would also love contours, lakes etc.

Free of course would be good.

US property outlines can require attribution

Comment: What do you mean with that final sentence *US property outlines can require attribution*?

Comment: Are you *sure* that such attribution requirements apply to maps printed on clothing? I wonder if the attribution requirement could be met by, for example, crediting the data source in the product listing, or by including it on the tag. Those would be good questions to investigate on [law.se]

Comment: This is a great question, by the way. If I was thinking about selling t-shirts with maps that I made, it never would have occurred to me that the public domain source data might require attribution. If you do post a question on [law.se], please link to it.

Answer (score 1):

one good option is http://www.naturalearthdata.com/, which is public domain

> Natural Earth is a public domain map dataset available at 1:10m, 1:50m, and 1:110 million scales.

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/about/terms-of-use/

> All versions of Natural Earth raster + vector map data found on this website are in the public domain. You may use the maps in any manner, including modifying the content and design, electronic dissemination, and offset printing.
>
> No permission is needed to use Natural Earth. Crediting the authors is unnecessary.

you can also see this geojson packaging of the data described above:  http://geojson.xyz/